# Lisp `characterp` returns nil everytime

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a program and would like to check what elements of a list are characters.
However, I am never able to make the `characterp` predicate to `T`.

The output of this snippet of code is `NIL`

```
(print (characterp 'c))
```

My current theory is that `c` is not a character but an atom that is not a number or a symbol. If I am using the inappropriate predicate, which predicate can help me return `T` when I pass a "character" and `NIL` otherwise?

Comment: `C` in your snippet is a symbol. A character literal would be written `#\c`.

Comment: To check for a symbol you ca use `(symbolp 'c)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `c` is a symbol with the name `"c"`.  This name is a string with one character in it.

A character literal is written like `#\c` in Common Lisp:

```
(characterp #\c)
⇒ T
```

If you want instead to ask the question “Is this a symbol with a name of length 1?”, you need to say so:

```
(= 1 (length (symbol-name 'c)))
⇒ T
```

Answer (score 4):

> My current theory is that `c` is not a character

You don't need a theory. Lisp is for interactive use and can tell you what things are. Just ask Lisp about the type:

```
CL-USER 11 > (type-of 'c)
SYMBOL

CL-USER 12 > (type-of "c")
SIMPLE-TEXT-STRING

CL-USER 13 > (type-of #\c)
CHARACTER
```